# To show the subcategory of the same category on the images page Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I want to show the same category's subcategory on my images page.
But when I am using foreach loop then all subcategory view is happening.

demo- https://oyewallpaper.com/photo/28529/rashmika-mandanna-saree-whatsapp-dp-pics-images

```xml
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <h4 style="margin-top:-5px;">Related</h4> 
  <div class="projects-catalog" style=" margin-bottom: -15px;margin-top: -10px;"> 
    <div class="catalog-cover"> 
      <i class="left-button"></i> 
      <ul class="sliderWrapper1 sliderscroll">
        @foreach( App\Models\SubCategories::where('subcategories_id', $response->categories_id)->get() as $subcategories )
          <?php 
            if( $subcategories->thumbnail == '' ) {
              $_image = 'default.jpg';
            } else {
              $_image = $subcategories->thumbnail;
            }
          ?>     
          <li class="slide">
            <a class="slink sq" href="{{ url('s',$subcategories->slug) }}">
              <img height="80" width="102" loading="lazy" class="img-circle sqtags" src="{{asset('public/img-category')}}/{{ $_image }}">
              <div class="sidekro chapta">
                <p>{{ $subcategories->name }}</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        @endforeach
        <a class="slink viewmore" href="{{ url('c', $response->category->slug) }}">
          <div class="sidekro viewmore1" style="margin: 4px;">
            <p>View</p>
            <p>more</p>
          </div>
        </a> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure `$response->categories_id` has the correct value?

Comment: i mean response $response->subcategories_id